# Non semisimple group representation

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose $k$ is a field of characteristic $7$ and let $G = \mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$. Show that the only simple representation of $G$ over $k$ is the trivial representation.

I have seen a proof of this that goes as follows:

$kG \cong k[x]/\langle x^7-1\rangle = k[x]/\langle (x-1)^7\rangle$. Therefore, since $k[x]/\langle (x-1)^7\rangle$ only has one simple submodule, the result follows.

I understand the sequence of isomorphisms and equalities, using the freshman's dream lemma in characteristic $7$. But I don't understand how the result follows from the fact that there is only one simple submodule.

I don't know why simple representations correspond to simple submodules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figured it out. It's not that $kG$ only has one simple submodule, it's that $kG$ only has one maximal ideal, and since any simple $kG$ module is isomorphic to $kG/I$ for some maximal ideal $I$, it follows that there can only be one simple $kG$-module so it must correspond to the trivial representation.